# Trying to do animation but the program would close before it

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner and was wondering if there was any way to finish the current animation before the program closes. Here is the sample of the code:

```
    if playerHealth <= 0: # If the player dies
        expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center, 'lg')
        all_sprites.add(expl) # Show animation of him blowing up
        running = False # End the game
```

Basically the running = False code would run before the animation(expl) starts. Is there a better way of showing this animation fully?

Comment: Never programmed games or looked at `pygame` but what about a delay? `import time
time.sleep(5) #5 seconds`

Comment: In fact, if you look at `pygame` docs, there is a [time](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) module with `pygame`. It has the functions that will probably help you. E.g: `pygame.time.wait()` or `pygame.time.delay()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a case for using a callback function. Pygame's [animation](http://pygame-zero.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builtins.html#animations) class has the `on_finished` property which is intended to be assigned to a callback. The callback would be called once the animation is finished playing and would stop the game. Here's an example Explosion class.

```
class Explosion:

    def __init__(self, rect, size, cb_func):

         self.animate_explosion(cb_func)

    ...

    def animate_explosion(self, cb_func):
         # start animation here

         ...

         # when animation finishes
         self.on_finished = cb_func()
```

And then within your game logic you have something like the following:

```
def callback():
     running = False

if playerHealth <= 0: # If the player dies
     expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center, 'lg', callback())
     all_sprites.add(expl) # Show animation of him blowing up
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably You need more modifications, but one of them is:

```
if playerHealth <= 0 and not blowing_up_animation_started: # If the player dies
    expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center, 'lg')
    all_sprites.add(expl) # Show animation of him blowing up

    blowing_up_animation_started = True
    blowing_up_animation_finished = False

if blowing_up_animation_finished:
    running = False # End the game
```